# Should features from gems be tested inside applications using them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, tdd, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a Rails 4 project. Naturally there are some gems that I use to add some features to the application.

One of these gems is the [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) gem.

I use it to add a search scope to the User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch

  pg_search_scope :search,
    against: [:email],
    using: :tsearch
end
```

The internal workings of such a scope are all tested within the gem.

So my question is, should this feature be tested within  my application as well? And if so how would such a test look like?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel And a long elaborate answer? :)

Comment: No because the point of a gem is that you don't have to test it in your app, that has been done for you by gem authors and contributors. I think it's even considered a wrongdoing to test a gem.

Comment: That is true. But what if some other gem I use interferes with the search method that is added to instances of the User model. Or some code I write myself breaks it. If I don't test whether my User model has a search method, how would I find out that it's broken.

Comment: In general a gem should be written in such way that it could not interfere with other gems. It is being considered a bad design if a gem (not talking about Rails at the moment) changes other classes methods. Can you give more specific examples - what gems, etc?

Comment: Let's say you use two gems that both implement a search method. Accidentily you include both in your model. (You want to replace one with another but forget to remove the original one). This changes or breaks the search functionality in your model. Shouldn't that pop up when you run the tests? Isn't it part of a tests' purpose to show it when a developer makes a mistake?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, that's something you should test. But I'm not sure that having two gems that both add search method on AR is a good think to do. Does Rails ensure library loading order?

Comment: I don't think it does. But I am not quite sure. I agree with you that having two gems that both add a search method to AR is probably a bad idea. But you might end up with them nonetheless. Espescially when this happens unintentionally, I think you want your tests to fail.

Comment: I think the general guide is: Do not test the internals of gems, but test the integration of those gems into your app. For example, I wouldn't test `pg_search` at all, but I would test a `search` method that used `pg_search`.

Answer (score 1):

Testing the gem itself is a bit insulting, as a gem has presumably been thoroughly tested already by developers/contributors. There is nothing wrong, however, with testing how the gem's features work with your own code. Excellent question though!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't unit test other people's code, but during integration testing I'll make sure that I'm interacting with the code in a correct fashion.

The reason for this is "DRY". Don't Repeat Yourself. If the code is already tested, adding the same tests again is adding code duplication.

Comment: I agree with your point. However, I find it hard to see how one would test such a thing. Could you provide an example, preferably based on the example from my question?